# TF-IDF raises AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower' even though there are no ints in he data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to perform TF-IDF transformation on a data set, using `sklearn`'s `TfidfVectorizer`.

I am receiving the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-212-ded21402d527> in <module>
----> 1 noise_tf = tfidf.fit(noise_data)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit(self, raw_documents, y)
   1629         """
   1630         self._check_params()
-> 1631         X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1632         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1633         return self

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1056 
   1057         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1058                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1059 
   1060         if self.binary:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    968         for doc in raw_documents:
    969             feature_counter = {}
--> 970             for feature in analyze(doc):
    971                 try:
    972                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <lambda>(doc)
    350                                                tokenize)
    351             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
--> 352                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
    353 
    354         else:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <lambda>(x)
    254 
    255         if self.lowercase:
--> 256             return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
    257         else:
    258             return strip_accents

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I made sure that the data does not contain any `int`s:

```py
>> noise_data.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int)).sum()
0
```

Then I just:

```py
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 5)
noise_tf = tfidf.fit(noise_data)
```

and got the above-mentioned error.

I'd expect this code to work fine as there are no `int`s in the data.

Any ideas what can be the cause of `TfidfVectorizer` raising this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question, but as I haven't found a similar topic on StackOverflow, I decided to keep the question here for others.

It seems that column names are also being taken into account by `TfidfVectorizer`.

I checked all column names' types and there were `int`s there. I casted all the column names to `string` and this solved the problem.

I am not sure why `TfidfVectorizer` tries to apply `.lower()` to column names, but apparantly it does. If anyone here has an idea what is the purpose of this - I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Perhaps you should raise an issue on their Github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn